# External resource allocation and de-allocation pattern

Tags: c++

Say I have an object that needs another object to be constructed as well as destructed, Foo needs Bar to create its backing resource (Bar creates and destroys the resource Foo holds and modifies), should I be storing a (shared) pointer to Bar inside of Foo? Should Bar be tracking the Foo objects it has made, how would you handle a Foo object going out of scope in that case? Other ideas?
Is this a bad pattern? How else should I be doing it?

```cpp
class Bar { ... }

class Foo {
  Bar *bar;
  Resource *resource;

public:
  Foo(Bar *bar) : bar(bar) {
    resource = createResource(bar);
  }

  ~Foo() {
    destroyResource(bar, resource);
  }

  // Other functions to interact with and modify resource, bar is not needed to perform these other operations, only for allocating and deallocating the resource.
}
```

To give a more concrete explanation of what I am after, I'm working with a C library called Vulkan Memory Allocator. It has its own types for allocations and buffers as well as a type that allows you to create and destroy allocations/buffers. In order to call destroy and create these resources, you need to have access to a VmaAllocator instance, additionally the resources may only be destroyed by the same instance they were created by. So my question is ultimately a life-cycle question, namely; should I be storing the pointer to this allocator and using it inside of the destructor to destroy the resources, or should I be using a factory pattern, or some other pattern? I'm aware that the allocator owns these resources, but I'm not sure how to handle these resources going out of scope should I make another class that handles creating allocations, thus taking away the responsibility of creating (and deleting) the backing resources from the Foo class itself.

Comment: This question feels very broad, but as a rule: you should use a shared pointer if you  need to hold multiple copies of the pointer; you should use a unique pointer if you want exactly one copy. These have their own construction, destruction, move, and copy semantics.

Comment: @erip I'm actually not sure how to narrow it down further, the problem is I don't exactly know what the correct pattern is for this. The Bar class as well as the createResource and destroyResource methods are provided by a library (Vulkan Memory Allocator), and I'm writing my own wrapper around buffer objects. I'm not sure if I should be having my own wrapper around the allocator object (Bar) as well, or if this kind of pattern is fine? How else can I get more specific?

Comment: Look at `std::shared_ptr<>` and `std::weak_ptr<>` and `std::unique_ptr<>` and avoid raw owning pointers and the additional complexity they add.

Comment: I've added a more clear description of the problem @erip Hopefully this clarifies what I am after enough

Comment: @Foxie: You're giving the wrong details. I mean, it's useful to know that the library creating these resources is external to your code, but what matters more is how you *intend* for ownership of these resources to work. Who has the responsibility for saying "I'm done using this" and how should that happen?

Comment: Userland code could delete your resources which leads to potential double frees. This is why smart pointers will solve your problem, but the question is which kind of smart pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas The allocation created should be solely owned by this Foo wrapper, and it should be deleted when the instance of this class is deconstructed. So I should be storing a pointer to the allocator inside of Foo then and using that to delete as I am doing in my example?